Mono Timeout in flatMap - Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 20000ms in 'flatMap' (and no fallback has been configured)
I'm working with Spring WebFlux to make a POST request and am getting following error:

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
Did not observe any item or
terminal signal within 20000ms in 'flatMap'
(and no fallback has been
configured)

Here's my code:
public Mono<ResponseEntity<XXXResponse>> invokeXXXService(XXXRequest request) {

        return webClient
                .baseUrl(XXXUrl)
                .build()
                .post()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.toEntity(XXXResponse.class))
                .timeout(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(20000))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                    LOG.error("Errors while getting res from XXX");
                    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(500).body(null));
                });
    }

It looks like the request is timing out after 20 seconds.

What might be causing this TimeoutException in my WebFlux WebClient?
Would increasing the timeout help, or is there a better way to handle it? If so, how can I do that with Reactor?

Any tips for handling this more gracefully would be great!

I guess I got your issue.
See this similar github issue : Memory leak with webclient timeout

What might be causing this TimeoutException in my WebFlux WebClient?


This is because the whole operation/process took more than 20s when
the call was made to API. and Mono.timeout takes into consideration
of each and every time that was taken from making the connection to
getting the response. So, you should avoid using Mono.timeout if you
want more granular timeout control.


Would increasing the timeout help, or is there a better way to handle it? If so, how can I do that with Reactor?


Workaround solution is to increase timeout in Mono.timeout but that
would be a temporary fix. Not a permanent fix.
Permanent fix to introduce timeout for various steps of a HTTPClient. Assuming that you are already aware of where the more time is consumed.
For your issue, better way would be to solve this issue is via setting
responseTimeout through HttpClient for response level timeout and passing it in the WebClient and also not using the Mono.timeout.

HttpClient client = HttpClient.create().responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(20000));  

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).baseUrl(XXXUrl).build();

public Mono<ResponseEntity<XXXResponse>> invokeXXXService(XXXRequest request) {

    return webClient
            .post()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
            .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.toEntity(XXXResponse.class))
            .onErrorResume(Throwable.class, ex -> {
                if (ex instanceof ReadTimeoutException) {
                    // put some logic that makes sense to be kept when reading from API fails.. 
                    return Mono.just("do something when timeout happens when reading the data..");
                } else if (ex instanceof WriteTimeoutException) {
                   // put some logic that makes sense to be kept when writing data via API fails.. 
                   return Mono.just("do something when timeout happens while writing the data via API..");  
                } else {
                   LOG.error("Errors while getting res from XXX");
                   return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(500).body(null)); exception ...");
                }
            });
}

Note: You can control timeout at the request level, connection level, read/write level and many more via HttpClient at the granularity.
This is just an example. Adjust it accordingly based on your requirements.
FYI: There is an excellent blog covering on how to config different timeout for Spring WebFlux's WebClient. Refer here.
